# Incorrect Query - Retrieval within ANY 12 month period

Tags: mysql, sql

The following query does not retrieve the correct results - it retrieves all member_id who have ordered twice. I need to find the member_id who have ordered twice within **any** 12 month period.

```
SELECT t1.member_id
FROM orders as t1
left JOIN orders as t2
ON t1.member_id = t2.member_id
AND (t2.date_paid>= DATE_SUB(t1.date_paid,INTERVAL 12 MONTH) and t2.date_paid<=t1.date_paid)
GROUP by member_id
HAVING COUNT(t1.order_id) >= 2
```

Comment: Your question require more details. Please post data sample, current query output and expected query output [into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69545693/edit). Currently I'm seeing that if _"ordered twice within 12 months"_ is the only condition, I don't think there's a reason for a self-join.

Answer (score 0):

would exclude rows for t1.date_paid = t2.date_paid:

```
select t1.member_id from orders as t1
  inner join orders as t2
    on t1.member_id = t2.member_id
    and t2.date_paid >= (t1.date_paid - interval '12' month) 
    and t2.date_paid < t1.date_paid
group by member_id
having count(t1.order_id) >= 2;
```

SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b68fb7/8)

Comment: .. and use INNER JOIN.